# How can Excel recognize a merged cell's value automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Unquestionably it's too unproductive to change the formula for C2-C4 singly. Please don't ask me to un-merge A1-A4.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need to multiply the content of Cell A1 (5) with the content of the Cells B1 to B4. Am I right? if yes this is the solution, please use absolute address of Cell A1 ($A$1) in Cell C2 and drag the formula down. Please follow below step:

1. Select Cell C1
2. Type =
3. Click the Cell A1
4. Press F4 (Function Key) it will make the cell address of A1 to its absolute address $A$1
5. Press *
6. Click the Cell B1
7. Press Enter key
8. Drag the Formula Down

[image]